# Virtual game dimensions - how to implement?

Tags: libgdx, camera, coordinates

I'm creating a fighting game in LibGDX with a static board, camera moves only right<>left.

There are 5 screen aspect ratios in Android and Apple so I have created 5 different background graphics:

- 2560x1440 16:9
- 2560x1920 4:3
- 2700x1800 3:2
- 3000x1800 5:3
- 3200x2800 8:5

Each background width is multiplied by 1.5, cause I need to zoom-out the game when players are too far away from each other, so for example 16:9 isn't 2560x1440 but 3840x1440. (I just realised that I should expand the height too LOL, gamedev is a fantastic place).

When I load the background I check the screen size and scale the background to fit.

The thing I need to implement is: Virtual Coordinates which are the same for each device.

Let's get the screen below:

[image]

I need to set virtual board dimensions to for example 2000x1000 units/meters whatever.

When the server sends a message:
Spawn a bomb on (1000,1000), left device spawns it at x=512, right device at x=960 (both on the half).

I think working on pixels is a bad idea, cause I would need to calculate things with each move, jump etc.

If someone could help me, how should I achieve this, I would be grateful for pointing me a way.

Thanks!

Comment: If you get width and height of specific device, you can divide it for example by 1000, and as a result you have a "point" which size is very similiar to others on other devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports). Many of the `Viewport` subclasses take virtual height and width in their constructors. There are different flavors of viewport depending on how well you want Libgdx to keep to your desired aspect ratio.